# crashlytics android high dex method count

Tags: google-fabric

ran over 64k android method limit!  Here's the section showing the Fabric.io libraries.  It seems they are more than the typical library by quite a margin, with over 2400 methods in multiple libraries.  Can this be resolved?  any way to reduce these manually?  Any way to remove BETA libraries while still using Crashlytics?

```
  2462 io.fabric.answers.android.unity
  2462 io.fabric.beta.android.unity
  2462 io.fabric.crashlytics.android.unity
    82 io.fabric.sdk.android
     2 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.cache
   169 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common
    58 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency
    22 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.internal
    38 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.events
    97 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network
     9 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.persistence
   207 io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings
  2462 io.fabric.sdk.android.unity
  2491 io.fabric.unity.android
  2468 io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.android
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. All of our Unity code in total is a little under 2500 methods. My hunch is that there may be other plugins or libraries that are contributing more to the Dex limit you're hitting. You could also consider using ProGuard to solve the issue.

Comment: hi @MikeBonnell!  thanks for the response.  The snippet from above is the output from the android build process in Unity, so clearly something in the process is causing it to be calculated incorrectly.  It seems to be counting it 6x in fact.  On a hunch, I tried moving the beta jar file into the libs folder for crashlytics, and this put me under the limit(!).  so i wonder if because each kit is in its own subfolder, it's causing it to count all the dependencies together(?).  not sure!